# Drawing thin shapes without losing quality or being blurry

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shapes, drawing

I want to draw an "x" and the size needs to be 8 × 8 and 10 × 10 but I can't do it without losing quality and it being blurry.

I tried in Photoshop and Illustrator, I tried to draw it big and then resize and I tried to draw it in 8 × 8 but no matter what I do when it is 8 × 8 or 10 × 10 it gets blurry and thick. I tried using a rectangle, line or even with a letter.

How can I draw a small thin "x" like the Microsoft Edge close button?

[image: here is an example for the x i want to draw]

Comment: I would try and draw it with SVG or use text instead of drawing so that it can resize to any size keeping its ratio and quality.

Comment: I need output as png file and i did use text but result is same it is very blury and thick

Comment: You appear to have zoomed in on the pixels. Set the zoom in Photoshop to 100%, and it won't look blurry.

Comment: Thanks billy :) actualy my problem is opposite when i zoomed in i see clearly every pixel but the problem starts when is it %100 size, in this case 8x8, as you can see in the image of microsoft edge close button, it seems very clear and thin and that is what i want to do, draw an x without blurry

Comment: your screenshot looks like you zoomed in, perhaps you should post a screenshot at 100% size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "blur" is just anti-aliasing, which is generally exactly what you want, otherwise everything looks jagged and pixelated.

You actually can't turn anti-aliasing off for shape *layers* in Photoshop, so (if that is what you're doing) you'll either have to use the shape tools in "fill pixels" mode on and uncheck "Anti-alias" or just draw the shapes yourself...

The following is an "X" drawn as a shape layer (on the left) vs one drawn pixel by pixel with a 1px wide pencil (on the right)...

[image]

If you're using text to create your "X" then you can set the anti-aliasing mode to "None" (bottom right of the Character panel)...

[image]

But as you can see, getting the pixels to fall in the right place can be a challenge...

8 × 8 pixels and 10 × 10 pixels are small enough sizes that drawing the shapes yourself — pixel by pixel — makes the most sense.

Comment: Mate you are a genious, thank you :), drawing pixel by pixel     with a pencil did exactly what i wanted