# Photoshop Pen Tool is very pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

When drawing with Photoshop's Pen Tool, the pen drawing looked very pixelated and not smooth:
[image: photoshop pen tool]

Is it supposed to look like that? If not, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing thin shapes without losing quality or being blurry](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91283/drawing-thin-shapes-without-losing-quality-or-being-blurry)

Comment: Are you working in something like "Bitmap" mode with a grey brush??? That's the *only* way I can replicate this issue.

Comment: Your document resolution may also be very low.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your artboard image size may be too small. The resolution of your document is very important.

Comment: PPiI/Resolution settings won't cause artifacts like that. If it were a PPI issue you'd see "blocky", "chunky", *pixels* - i.e. squares.